# How to create a function handle using the symbol for an already defined function

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, symbolic-math

Simple as can be

say

```
syms x
f = x.^2
d = @(x) f
```

MATLAB does not like this.

For example, if I try `integral(d,0,2)`, I get an error.

I am using the Maple Symbolic Toolbox.

Obviously, what I want MATLAB to understand is that I mean `d = @(x) x.^2`. How can I make MATLAB understand this, without of course writing it out explicitly for just `x.^2` or some fixed function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `matlabFunction` to convert symbolic functions to function handles:

```
d=matlabFunction(f)
```

Comment: I'm using r2013a...I think I need 2014b to use matlabFunction.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use either of these (tested in Matlab R2014b):

- `d = f;`
- `d = @(x) f(x);`